# onehotencoder issue

Tags: neural-networks, python, keras

New to DNN. I have the following dataset
[image]

My target value is "Purchase" column. I know I need to drop "product_id" column and create dummies for "Gender" and "City_category", but do i need to do onehotencoder on any other column even if they are not categorical? 
(for instance Stay_In_City_Years)
If so, can you explain the reason.  thanks for any help

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? How would making a quantity like "number of years" into a one-hot encoded value help solve that problem?

Comment: I am trying to predict purchase price. My general question is, do we onehotencoder only on categorical data or, in some circumstances ,on numerical columns as well?